# Make CMake variable set in subproject (variable nesting) available to all other subprojects

Tags: cmake

If I have a similar to the following structure project tree (each subproject is added via `add_subdirectory()` to the parent project):

```
CMakeLists.txt (TOP-LEVEL)
    |
    + -- subproj1
    |       |
    |       + -- CMakeLists.txt (subproj1)
    |       |
    |       + -- subsubproj1
    |                 |
    |                 + -- CMakeLists.txt (subsubproj1)
    |
    + -- subproj2
            |
            + -- CMakeLists.txt (subproj2)
```

I want to expose a variable set inside `subsubproj1` in `subproj2`. The nature of this variable is irrelevant but in my case it points at `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include` that is the include directory of `subsubproj1`, which (in my case) is a library used by `subproj2`. Currently I am re-assigning the variable in each intermediate `CMakeLists.txt` between the one (here `subproj1`) where the variable was assigned a value to the top-level with `PARENT_SCOPE` enabled:

**CMakeLists.txt (subsubproj1)**

```
# Expose MY_VAR to subproj1
set(MY_VAR
    "Hello"
    PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

**CMakeLists.txt (subproj1)**

```
# Expose MY_VAR to top level project thus making it visible to all
set(MY_VAR
    ${MY_VAR}
    PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

This can be applied to an arbitrary nested project tree.

My question is what is the common practice of doing what I have described above? I can declare `MY_VAR` as a top-level variable to begin with but what if for some reason I don't want to make it visible (as in written text) there. In which case is `PARENT_SCOPE` no longer an option and should be replaced with just a straight declaration of that variable in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: You stated that `I want to expose a variable set inside subsubproj1 in subproj2`. So: `In which case is PARENT_SCOPE no longer an option and should be replaced with just a straight declaration of that variable in the top-level CMakeLists.txt?` I do not understand, in such case the variable is not set inside `subsubproj1`, so your requirement is violated, so in no case should it be replaced.  `what is the common practice of doing` The common practice _when_ you want to set a variable in `subsubproj1` to be available to parents is to use `PARENT_SCOPE`.

Comment: Might you be less broad to your use case? How do you intent to use your variable? What for? What is the purpose of that variable and how `subproj2` intents to use it? What does the variable affect and how it's value changes?

Comment: I will add details on the nature of the variable.

Comment: Usually you'd use a cache variable. This makes the variable visible everywhere, but you don't need to worry about passing the variable through the directory hierarchy. Considering your description of this being a include directory though, I don't see a reason not to add the dir to a target via `target_include_directory` with public or interface visibility which provides makes sure all linking libraries gain access to this include directory, even if they link indirectly (as long as every link except for the last is done with public or interface visibility).

Answer (score 1):

### Targets

> The nature of this variable is irrelevant but in my case it points at `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include` that is the include directory of subsubproj1, which (in my case) is a library used by subproj2.

**No, the nature is not irrelevant**.

Using variables to communicate include directories in CMake is a horrible anti-pattern from the 2.6.x days. You should not use a hammer to drive in a screw.

Non-`IMPORTED` projects are always global, so you can link to them safely. In `subsubproj1` you would write:

```
add_library(myproj_subsubproj1 INTERFACE)
add_library(myproj::subsubproj1 ALIAS myproj_subsubproj1)

target_include_directories(
  myproj_subsubproj1
  INTERFACE
    "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
)
```

Then in `subproj2`, you would write:

```
target_link_libraries(myproj_subproj2 PRIVATE myproj::subsubproj1)
```

### Worse options

The following options are worse because they forego the declarative parts of the CMake language and make your scripts dependent on subproject inclusion order. This is a significant complexity increase that (in my experience) is not warranted in build code.

Nevertheless, here are the imperative tools CMake provides:

#### 1. Using a `CACHE` variable

The cache is a disk-persisted store for global variables. Setting one in any directory makes the value visible to *all* directories.

Note that there are a few potential drawbacks to this:

1. Prior to CMake 3.21, creating a new cache entry would delete a normal variable of the same name, leading to tricky situations where builds could become *non-idempotent* (bad!). See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0126.html
2. The user can overwrite your cache variables at the command line, so you cannot rely on either the defined-ness or the value of the variable when your CMake program starts running.

If you can live with this, then you can write:

```
# On CMake <3.21, honor normal variables. Can remove
# check if on CMake >=3.21
if (NOT DEFINED MyProj_INADVISABLE_VARIABLE)
  set(MyProj_INADVISABLE_VARIABLE
      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
      CACHE STRING "Doc string...") 
  # If you want to hint to your users that they should
  # not edit this variable, include the following line:
  mark_as_advanced(MyProj_WEIRD_VARIABLE)
endif ()
```

If you do not want to allow your users to override it, then you may consistently use an `INTERNAL` cache variable:

```
set(MyProj_INADVISABLE_VARIABLE "..." CACHE INTERNAL "...")
```

As long as you initialize it to a known value early on, then this will work okay as a global variable, but might incur disk traffic on writes.

#### 2. Directory property

A slightly better approach is to use a custom directory property to communicate a value. In `subsubproj1`:

```
set_property(DIRECTORY "." PROPERTY inadvisable_prop "foo")
```

Then in `subproj2`:

```
get_property(value DIRECTORY "../subproj1/subsubproj1"
             PROPERTY inadvisable_prop)
```

Note that it is not an error to get a non-existent property, so be on the lookout for types.

You *could* also use a `GLOBAL` property instead of a directory property, but global variables in general are a headache waiting to happen. You might as well set it on the directory to decrease the chances of unintended scoping bugs.